GitHub Apps JWT to Installation Token via PowerShell
I'm trying to determine how to retrieve an installation token from my GitHub App using PowerShell.
Generating JWT based on private PEM
Following code is used which is basically copied from the GitHub guide.
function Generate-JWT-FromGithub
{
    $client_id = <<APP_ID>>
    $private_key_path = <<LOKAL_PATH_TO_MY_PEM_FILE>>
    try {
        $header = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes((ConvertTo-Json -InputObject @{
            alg = "RS256"
            typ = "JWT"
            }))).TrimEnd('=').Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_');
        
            $payload = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes((ConvertTo-Json -InputObject @{
            iat = [System.DateTimeOffset]::UtcNow.AddSeconds(-10).ToUnixTimeSeconds()
            exp = [System.DateTimeOffset]::UtcNow.AddMinutes(10).ToUnixTimeSeconds()
                iss = $client_id
            }))).TrimEnd('=').Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_');

            $rsa = [System.Security.Cryptography.RSA]::Create()
            $rsa.ImportFromPem((Get-Content $private_key_path -Raw))
        
            $signature = [Convert]::ToBase64String($rsa.SignData([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("$header.$payload"), [System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithmName]::SHA256, [System.Security.Cryptography.RSASignaturePadding]::Pkcs1)).TrimEnd('=').Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_')
            $jwt = "$header.$payload.$signature"
            return $jwt
    }
    catch {
        Handle-Error $_.Exception.Message
    }
}

Get Installation Token from GitHub API
function Get-InstallationToken {
    param(
        $JwtToken,        
        $InstallationId    
    )

    $Headers = @{
        Authorization = "Bearer $JwtToken"
        Accept        = "application/vnd.github.v3+json"
        "X-GitHub-Api-Version" = "2022-11-28"
    }
    $Url = "https://api.github.com/app/installations/$InstallationId/access_tokens"
    $Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $Url -Headers $Headers

    return $Response.token
}

Call in PowerShell 7
$InstallationId = <<ID_FROM_MY_GITHUB_APP>>
$JwtToken = Generate-JWT-FromGithub 
$InstallationToken = Get-InstallationToken -JwtToken $JwtToken -InstallationId $InstallationId

Following issue I'm facing
Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
I made sure that the PEM file is valid. Also I checked twice the APP_ID and Installation ID.
Results all the time in "Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized)."

There must be a small typo in the code.
To find out, base64-encode JwtToken in your workflow and then output it to stdout.
Run the workflow, find the output, decode it and retrieve JWT token. Then use
https://jwt.io/

to read the token contents.
Make sure that token is valid.
